# Prevent Wordpress from looipng and auto playing the next tracks using Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

According to my [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37012165/how-to-stop-the-wordpress-audio-playlist-from-playing-the-next-soundtracks-autom) I finally managed to prevent Wordpress from looping and playing the next soundtracks automatically editing these lines of codes in wp-playlist.min.js :

For the next soundtracks I deleted this:
this.tracks.length?this.next():

and for the loop I changed this:

```
(this.index=0,this.setCurrent())}
```

to this:

```
(this.index=0)
```

Now I know if I upgrade my Wordpress it will reset these settings and I'm looking for a way to have it in my footer.php because there are some other modified codes inside `<script type="text/javascript"> </script>` that fixes some other issues...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin that has a copy of wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-playlist.min.js in it with your chances. Then unload the other version and load this version of the file with:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_mediaelement_changes' );
function my_mediaelement_changes() {
        wp_deregister_script( 'wp-playlist' );
        wp_register_script( 'wp-playlist', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "/js/wp-playlist.min.js", array( 'mediaelement' ), false, true );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm no coder and I'm looking for an easy to use solution. I thought maybe putting a simple Javascript code in my footer.php would fix the problem.

Comment: Honestly if your not a developer I wouldn't mess with this. Overwriting core functions can lead to trouble.

Comment: 1. it is not ME who's going to mess with the codes, it would definitely be YOU as a developer.

2. I've fixed many issues with the help of programmers and it's not a must to be a developer in the first place to be qualified for asking a question here.

3. I'm working on my website offline. there would be no trouble at all.

4. I can read codes to some extend but can't write them.

5. The question is so straight forward. if you have no idea how to help, please never give anyone such an advice.

Thanks for your attention

Comment: I wasn't trying to insult you. I'm also not sure why you are referencing me looking at the code when you are the one editing it. One mistake and you're site doesn't function. Since you don't seem to be familiar enough with the code you may not be able to recover. I think my advice was sound and I would advise you to take it.

Comment: After every storm the sun will smile. for every problem there is a solution. William R. Alger       
According to 3 there will be no problem and when there is MySQLDumper there is a way. But thanks for your advice. I'll be careful :)